# shopify sortable does not scroll during drag

Tags: javascript, scroll, shopify, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I have created a small demo here https://codepen.io/domnulnopcea/pen/ZqGJjJ

It is basically a trello clone using the draggable library from shopify

I am using sortable for drag and drop items.

```
const sortable = new Draggable.Sortable(document.querySelectorAll('ul'), {
    draggable: 'li',
    mirror: {
        constrainDimensions: true,
    },
    plugins: [Draggable.Plugins.ResizeMirror]
});
```

Now, if you grab one cell from the first column and you want to drop it in the last column it will not trigger the horizontal scroll.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of the library?

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Trigger horizontal scroll"? There is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the section.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiDas I mean the scroll bar does not move left or right when the mouse reaches the extremities of the screen

Comment: It moves. At least moved for me.

Comment: try multuple times @SubhrajyotiDas. it won't work after the second or third try

Comment: Sorry @Nopcea it works perfectly for me any number of times i try. You may try to forcibly move the screen when the mouse reaches the end of the screen.

Comment: I'm on a Mac. Your demo works fine in Safari, but not in Chrome. In Firefox it *partially* works but you have to wiggle the mouse around near the right edge to get it to scroll.